# Select every nth element in ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have two arraylists: arraylist 1 could be 1000s of elements long, arraylist 2 should be a maximum of 100 elements long.

How can I evenly select 100 elements from arraylist 1 to create arraylist 2? (e.g. selecting every nth element)?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Side note - Don't use `ArrayList`, it isn't type safe. Go with the generic `List<T>` approach instead.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by not type safe? Thanks

Comment: `ArrayList` holds inside it an `object[]`. This means that you can put in objects of type `string`, `int`, `MyCustomFooObject`, etc.